# Should I use the <center> tag?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, jsx

I'm using react, with bootstrap, and less. I was just wondering whether it was a better practice to use  `<center className="text-center">` when centering text for accessibility, or if I was better off just sticking with `<div className="text-center>`. Or does it even make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no difference for accessibility, but it's a bad idea for many other reasons, and depending on the doctype you use, might even violate WCAG SC 4.1.1.

Don't use deprecated presentational HTML tags if you can avoid it. And you can, with CSS and style attributes. `<center>` is completely obsolete in the 21st century.

Comment: Thanks I was just making sure to make sure I was writing the best code I can.

Comment: spot on, what did surprise me is `<center>` still works in Google Chrome! When I saw the question I thought it was a custom tag implemented by some library as I had forgotten all about it! +1 for the 4.1.1 link as although not specifically mentioned I had never thought about the fact it would fail POUR under the Robust part!

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use the `<center>` tag?

## Yes, but only if you're specifically targeting Netscape Navigator (before version 2.0).

Latest HTML3.2 references said that:

> `CENTER` was introduced by Netscape before they added support for the HTML 3.0 `DIV` element. It is retained in HTML 3.2 on account of its widespread deployment.

Otherwise, no ... as it will be deprecated [in 1997](https://www.w3.org/TR/PR-html40-971107/present/graphics.html#edef-CENTER).